# React Native / App Store Connect: ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, package.json

When I upload my app to the app store, I get a mail from the apple:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)

I am unable to understand which is the problem causing library in my code. If anyone would help me in figuring out the problem causing library, I'll be really thankful. When I run: `grep -r UIWebView ./*` Here is what happens[image] My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/ex-navigation": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.55.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-email": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "0.0.7",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "js/assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I faced the same problem and managed to solve it thanks to a [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63154520/11090321) that suggested to upgrade react-native version to latest.